# What is the inverse of the function $g(t)=1/(t+i)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $t\in C$ and consider the map

$$g(t)=\frac1 {t+i}$$

Find $g^{-1}$, the domain of $ g $ and the domain of $g^{-1}$?

For $g^{-1}(x)$ I get $\frac 1 x -i$, but i think that is incorrect.

Comment: Set $u=g(t)$ and express $t$ in terms of $u$. This is $t=g^{-1}(u)$.

Comment: Why do you think it is incorrect?  If you think it is incorrect (or even if you think it is correct), how can you check your answer?

Answer (score 1):

The domain of $\,g\,$ is $\,\Bbb C-\{-i\}\,$ , so this is the codomain of the inverse. Now

$$\exists\,w\in\Bbb C\,\,\,s.t.\,\,\,\frac{1}{t+i}=w\iff tw=1-wi\iff t=\frac{1-wi}{w}\iff w\neq 0$$

and we've found the inverse's domain...Now do as Julien suggested you to find the inverse (which, btw, is already somewhere out there...)